# login with google api just once using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api

I follow this example to log with my application with javascript
[example login with java script](http://hayageek.com/login-with-google-plus-javascript-api/)

it works fine but i want my application to log just once not every time I use this example to log.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by just once. What is the behavior needed ?

Comment: i use this example to get user data and posts every time i need to get user data , posts user need application to log but i need app to log just for first time and aftre that i could load user data , posts

Comment: But you cannot use users data if he is logged out. You will need his permission to log in. Javascript API allows limited time token, For longer token you will need to integrate it server side. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: i need only data while user is still logged with my application in this example if i reload page the user log out from application i want him to stay logged in

Comment: Well In that case you need to create local session, and store the data first time you get. Cause using JS there is no way you can persist the state, unless you can save it on localstorage.